# Acceder a un fichero desde una función

Tags: c++, archivo, punteros

Estoy tratando de poder acceder a una variable tipo FILE creada en la función main para poder editar el un archivo desde una función aparte, pero no consigo hacer que el archivo sea editado, este es el código que escribí:

```
void cambio(FILE *a);
int main(){
    FILE *archivo;
    char nombre[20],lectura;
    std::cout<<"Ingresa el nombre del archivo o su ubicacion: ";
    std::cin>>nombre;
    archivo=fopen(nombre,"w+");
    cambio(archivo);
    while(feof(archivo)==0){
        lectura=fgetc(archivo);
        std::cout<<lectura;
    }



}
void cambio(FILE *a){
    fputs("Añadido",a);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la función `cambio` no miras si `a` (de tipo `FILE *`) es válido; si no lo es no te escribirá datos, tampoco te los leerá después. Comprueba el estado del puntero antes de hacer cualquier operación, tampoco debes olvidar cerrar el archivo después de usarlo porque en caso de mantenerlo abierto tal vez no se abra en futuras llamadas a `fopen`:

```
char nombre[20], lectura;

std::cout << "Ingresa el nombre del archivo o su ubicacion: ";
std::cin >> nombre;

FILE *archivo = fopen(nombre,"w+");
if (archivo) // <--- Comprobar si se pudo abrir
{
    cambio(archivo);

    while (feof(archivo) == 0){
        lectura = fgetc(archivo);
        std::cout << lectura;
    }

    fclose(archivo); // <--- No olvides cerrar
}
else
    std::cout << "Error abriendo el archivo\n";
```

Mejor aún, dado que has etiquetado la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), usa las herramientas de ese lenguaje:

```
void cambio(std::fstream &f)
{
    f << "Añadido";
}

int main()
{
    std::string nombre;
    std::cout << "Ingresa el nombre y ubicacion del archivo: ";
    std::cin >> nombre;

    if (std::fstream archivo{nombre, std::ios::in | std::ios::out})
    {
        cambio(archivo);

        char lectura;
        while (archivo >> lectura)
            std::cout << lectura;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No se pudo abrir " << nombre << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```